# Scheme R5RS define-syntax ignored?

Tags: scheme, undefined, racket, define-syntax

Just started learning Scheme.
I'm using Dr. Racket as my compiler/interpreter.

I need some String functions (string-replace to be exact), so I copied from [SRFI 13](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-13/srfi-13.scm).

When I test it, it shows..

```
reference to undefined identifier: let-string-start+end
```

That's defined with

```
define-syntax let-string-start+end
```

It seems that it's being ignored? What's actually happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to manually copy and paste items from SRFI 13: it is built into Racket.  In fact, most of the major SRFI libraries are bundled with Racket: http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/index.html

If you are using the **r5rs** language in Racket, you can pull in SRFI 13 with the following line:

```
(#%require srfi/13)
```

The strange-looking `#%require` is a Racket-specific [hook](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs-mod.html#%28part._.Non-.R5.R.S_.Bindings_from_r5rs%29) that allows an r5rs program to load library modules from Racket.

So an r5rs program in Racket would be something like this:

```
(#%require srfi/13)
(display (string-replace "foo world" "hello" 0 3))
(newline)
```

---

If, instead of using the basic `r5rs` language, you use the full-fledged `#lang racket` instead, importing SRFI 13 would look similar.  Here's a small program in `#lang racket` that does the same as the previous program:

```
#lang racket
(require srfi/13)
(string-replace "foo world" "hello" 0 3)
```

---

Unfortunately, the error you're reporting doesn't have enough information to accurately diagnose the problem.  I suspect an incomplete copy-and-pasting somewhere, since you mention that you copied from SRFI 13.  One reason why I think you may have mis-copied the code is that you mention defining it with:

```
define-syntax let-string-start+end
```

and that line is actually missing some crucial parentheses; in the original source, there's a leading paren at the front of that line.

But you shouldn't try to cull bits and pieces out of the SRFI implementation by hand, at least not until you're more familiar with Scheme.  Simplify by loading the entire library.

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize "require".. Maybe because I'm using R5RS? Don't know :/

Comment: If you are using Racket's R5RS mode, you will instead need to use `(#%require srfi/13)`.

Comment: thanks so much guys, both method made it work.. and Chris, is that a standard syntax for R5RS? What's with the "#%"?

Comment: Glad to see it's working!  I've incorporated Chris's comment into the answer.  The #%require thing is a Racket-specific hook that lets a R5RS program pull in Racket modules.